# What does "thema.."<view_name> mean in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have got a query which is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM thema.."<view_name>".
```

When I check all the schema in the db, I am not able to see any schema name called thema. Is it something which is internal to sql server 2008?

Comment: if iti si followed by .., it is not a schema but a database name.

Comment: Why closing as not constructive?  It's hard to see how this question could solicit debate.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses up to four parts in a name: `server.database.schema.table`.  If you omit the schema name (f.e. `dbname..tablename`) SQL Server will use the default schema for your user.